# Insert php date using Javascript in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, date

For my wordpress website I am trying to remove the Google timestamp that is currently in my SERP (search page result description.)

To do this I must use javascript to get the time and report it back.

You may want to refer to this link: http://www.andrewkeir.com/remove-wordpress-post-datestamp-timestamp-google-serps/

and to another question here: [Need to insert javascript into php code [Wordpress Website]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390553/need-to-insert-javascript-into-php-code-wordpress-website)

The code in my template file is:

```
$out .= '<div class="info"><a class="date-left"></a><a href="'.get_month_link($year, $month).'" class="date">'.get_the_time('F j, Y').'</a><a class="date-right"></a>
```

and I need to get this code to work in its place:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">document.write("<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>");</script>
```

Appreciate any help/guidance on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically that first article you referenced is telling you that you need to wrap the code that determines the time using PHP (in your case the "get_the_time('F j, Y')" part) with Javascript that will write the exact same output to the document.  Therefore if you take your existing code:

```
$out .= '<div class="info"><a class="date-left"></a><a href="'.get_month_link($year, $month).'" class="date">'.get_the_time('F j, Y').'</a><a class="date-right"></a>
```

You'll probably want to do something like this:

```
$out .= '<div class="info"><a class="date-left"></a><a href="'.get_month_link($year, $month).'" class="date"><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">document.write('.get_the_time('F j, Y').');</script></a><a class="date-right"></a>
```